# mpi4py: Process communication with 4 processes deadlocks

Tags: python, mpi, mpich, mpi4py

I'm writing a program which should add chars to strings in three different processes. If the resulting string matches a given one, the process which has the match, should send an "endflag" to process 0. After process 0 receives the "endflag" he should send a broadcast to all other processes (1 - 3) and exit. The other processes receive the broadcast and should exit too / stop working.

```
[...]

string_given = "abc"
magic_bytes = "0xDEA7C0DE"
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 !?@/\%&.-_:,;*+<>|(){}'
end_all = None

if rank == 0:
    while(True):
        recv_data = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
        print("0.recv: %s" % (recv_data))
        if recv_data == magic_bytes:
            end_all = magic_bytes
            send_data = bcast(end_all, root=0)
            sys.exit()

if rank == 1:
    min, max = 1, 2
    while(True):
        for n in xrange(min, max):
            for c in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n):
                string = ''.join(c)
                print("1.string: %s" % (string))
                if string == string_given:
                    print("1.found: %s = %s" % (string, string_given))
                    end_all = magic_bytes
                    comm.send(end_all, dest=0)
                recv_data = comm.bcast(end_all, root=0)
                if recv_data == magic_bytes:
                    sys.exit()

if rank == 2:
    min, max = 3, 4
    while(True):
        for n in xrange(min, max):
            for c in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n):
                string = ''.join(c)
                print("2.string: %s" % (string))
                if string == string_given:
                    print("2.found: %s = %s" % (string, string_given))
                    end_all = magic_bytes
                    comm.isend(end_all, dest=0)
                recv_data = comm.bcast(end_all, root=0)
                if recv_data == magic_bytes:
                    sys.exit()

[...]
```

The code above produces following output:

```
 3.string: aaaaa
 1.string: a
 2.string: aaa
```

And then i think it deadlocks. 
How can i prevent my code from the deadlock?

Comment: Please add an error message and shorten your code if possible for better readability.

Comment: Adding an error message when the code deadlocks? That might take while :)

Comment: There is no error message available, it shows the output above and then nothing happens... even after several minutes. Actually, it should generate more strings within a few seconds.

Comment: Rank 0 only `MPI_Bcast()` when magic bytes are received, but other ranks always `MPI_Bcast()` and hang if none of them find the string. You might want to consider `MPI_Ibcast()` and `MPI_Test()` instead.

Comment: Gilles Gouaillardetdo you have a start-up point where i can learn more about `MPI_Test()` and `MPI_Bcast()`? Currently i've solved my problem with `os._exit(0)` which is exiting python and MPI after `string == string_given`. But i want a proper solution with "flags".